# UIScrollView AutoLayout With 'Footer' Pinned to Bottom of Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have been banging my head against a wall for a while with this. I need to have a UIScrollView with an arbitrary number of labels under each other and then have a header pinned to the top and a footer pinned to the bottom of the screen. All this needs to be using auto layout. Is this possible at all?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks,

Alex Crompton

Comment: A table view would be easier to implement that a scroll view with an arbitrary number of labels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it has to look like that

http://kernelmd.tumblr.com/image/114897924655

Just pin upper view to the top, bottom to the bottom, they must also have fixed sizes. Then for scroll view use relative vertical space to header and footer view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add header & footer view inside the scroll & add the labels in between & add constraints to header as top, leading, trailing, height. Then add constraint to labels as per your requirement & Finally add constraint to Footer view as leading, trailing, height & bottom. Bottom Constraint is must to know scrollView its content size.