# iOS Scrollable screen OR with a pinned footer using Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

This is **not** the same as [UIScrollView AutoLayout With 'Footer' Pinned to Bottom of Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324928/uiscrollview-autolayout-with-footer-pinned-to-bottom-of-screen).

I want to have a screen with contents of variable height plus a footer. When the contents are few, the footer should stick to the bottom and have a gap between it and the contents. When the contents are more than fits the screen, the screen should be scrollable and the footer should appear just after the contents.

```
Few contents:                  Lots of contents:

+---------+                     +---------+
| Content |                     | Content |
| Content |                     | Content |
| Content |                     | Content |
|         |                     | Content |
|         |                     | Content |
| Footer  |                     | Content |
+---------+  < Screen bottom >  +---------+
                                | Content |
                                | Footer  |
```

I would need it to be iOS7 compatible.

I don't have specific requirements regarding the implementation (scrollview, tableview, etc), but I'd like to do it all via autolayout (or any earlier way that does the thing automatically).

I wouldn't mind having some code to respond to the two different cases, as long as it would support dynamic content height. I'm not keen on monitoring UI size changes, but, if that can be done in a reasonably clean way, so be it.

Comment: In tableView you can do it pretty easily just set toolbar to footer of your tableView and it's done :)

Comment: @Misha could you expand? My problem is not in having the footer appear after the contents, it's in having it pinned to the bottom of the screen when the contents are few, but not when they aren't. I have tried using a UIToolbar as a table's footer, but it appears right after the contents, not pinned to the bottom.

Comment: is it still not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I misunderstood your question earlier. But I think this should work. Add a UIToolbar in ypur tableView

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [_tableView reloadData];

```
CGRect newFrame = _toolBar.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = _tableView.contentSize.height > CGRectGetHeight(_tableView.frame) ? _tableView.contentSize.height : CGRectGetHeight(_tableView.frame);
_toolBar.frame = newFrame;
}
```

I think code is self explainable. :)

Comment: thanks, I'll accept the answer, but it's not what I had in mind. My intent was to have it update automatically, via autolayout or otherwise. But as it is, I'll try to use a constraint that shrinks and expands in a way similar to your arithmetic above; I'm just not sure at this point when best to update its value. I'll also need to check that `contentSize` is dependable.

Comment: whenevr you reload your tableview it's contenetSize will change accordingly and so you can update height of toolbar